# Split MS Access database - can't open backend - potential security concern

Tags: ms-access, backend

I have developed a database in MS Access 365, created all the tables and objects, and successfully split the database (using the wizard) into a front- and back-end.

The front-end opens and runs fine.

However, I can't open the back-end to make design changes. The error I get is:

[image: security notice]

I've search and read about creating a digital signature, tried to create one locally, "sign and package" the database before splitting, but nothing has worked yet.

Does anyone know how to get this to work so I can open the back-end database file?

Comment: First look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409158/how-can-i-add-a-certificate-to-vba-access-project-if-the-digital-signature-item  and if that fails, look at this regarding setting a Digital Signature: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-trust-by-adding-a-digital-signature-2f6b7d18-a9d3-400d-9f63-9029551e61a1

Comment: Surely I shouldn't have to edit the registry to be able to open the backend of a database that I created and have saved locally??

Also, the message I'm getting is slightly different in that it doesn't give me the option to `open` at all. 

I've created a digital signature, packaged the database with it, saved it, then split it again and it still gives the same error.

Comment: From my reading the first article, the reason for the registry change is because they were using 2010 RUN-TIME which doesn't have an interface to add to trusted location. In my version of 2010 I can use the Trust Center to add a location. Google shows this article for Office 365: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179039(v=office.15).aspx (unfortunately this also modifies the registry)

Comment: Thanks. Rather than play about with registry settings on my client's machines I'm going to use the solution proposed here http://tinyurl.com/q63zraw , which basically says to create to copies, delete objects from one and tables from the other, then re-link the tables to the objects (basically manually splitting the database, rather than using the wizard).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen two answers to this issue (solution 2 is the simplest)

**Solution 1**

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-access/access-2013-split-database/26622a96-ddfc-4aba-98ac-aa83fd786e86

Split the database manually:

1. Take a backup copy of the database.
2. Take another copy of the database and rename it as the back-end (e.g. MyDatabase Data.accdb)
3. Open the new back-end and delete all the objects EXCEPT the tables.
4. Open the original database (which is now the front-end) and delete all the tables (except the system tables - MSys* - if they are visible)
5. Use External data > Import & Link > Access to link all the tables from the back-end to the front-end.

**Solution 2**

http://www.accessforums.net/access/problems-accessing-split-database-backend-48064.html

There is an issue with the split feature of Access 2013 in that it is creating the back end as .accdc rather than .accdb

The good news is the fix is simple; just manually change the file extension to .accdb

One interesting point on all this is that from the FE everything is fine - you can open tables no problem; but if you attempt to open the back end .accdc directly Access won't let you do it due to invalid certificate.