# Adding Trusted Location to Access Run Time

Tags: ms-access, runtime, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have created a Microsoft Access file.

How do I add this file to the trusted locations on my client's PC where there is only the runtime version of Access installed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Access 2007:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\Location(n)]
```

Access 2010:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\Location(n)]
```

Access 2013:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\Location(n)]
```

Access 2016 & Access 2019 & Office 365:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\Location(n)]
```

Example of how it will look

```
"Path"="C:\PathToDB\"
"AllowSubfolders"=dword:00000001
"Description"="The description"
"Date"="01.01.2007 12:00"
```

If editing Reg is not cup of your Tea, then use AddPath
http://www.accessribbon.de/en/?Trust_Center:Trusted_Locations

Answer (score 10):

Below are some instructions i found awhile ago which i had saved, which allow you to add trusted locations, allow network locations & include sub folders.

1. Use the search in Windows 7 or Windows 8 and type in "regedit.exe";
2. Allow Microsoft Windows Registry Editor to make changes to your system;
3. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations;
4. Add a DWORD by right clicking the Trusted Locations directory, selecting New > DWORD (32-bit) Value [or 64 bit QWORD as required];
5. Change the name of the DWORD to "AllowNetworkLocations";
6. Right click and modify the DWORD using "1" as the value;
7. Now add a new KEY to the Trusted Locations directory by right clicking the directory and selecting New > Key (You can rename this to something meaningful);
8. Right click the new Key and select New > Expandable String Value (for runtime 2013, just String Value for earlier version);
9. Change the name of this file to "Path" and then right-click and modify... the Value Data to the path or network name required (ie "Z:\" or "\servername" );
10. To include sub directories as trusted locations, add a DWORD by right clicking the new key, selecting New > DWORD (32-bit) Value [or 64 bit QWORD as required];
11. Change the name of this DWORD to "AllowSubfolders" and right click and modify... the DWORD using "1" as the value;

Answer (score 4):

It is much easier to just copy your Access file to a folder that is already trusted by any user.

One example is `%LocalAppData%` which works even in a Citrix environment.

Create a folder here named you or your company and a subfolder named your application. Copy you database file to this, and provide a shortcut for the users.

Full documentation here:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html)

Comment: This assumes that you are free to move files to where ever you wish.

Comment: Yes, you are always free to move files to your (the user's) folders.

Answer (score 3):

If the trusted location is on a network location then you need to add:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations]
"AllowNetworkLocations"=dword:00000001

Answer (score 2):

Just create a Windows registry entry under

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations]
```

And then add String Value entry "Path" and set desired path as value. Another String Value entry "Description" is required to add a description of the path.

[image]

e.g.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\Location3]
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, the equivalent put into HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE also works for all users (rather than the HKEY_CURRENT_USER which only works for the current user), tested for Access Runtime 365.