# How can I get a digital trust certificate for an Access executable file in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, vba, ms-access, exe, digital-certificate

In previous posts, I mentioned that I split my Access database project (Access 2016) in a front-end (Access) and back-end (MS-SQL). It was recommended that I save my front-end as an executable file, which I did. However, since it has macros and vba code, I always get a security warning.

I need a digital trust certificate, right? The problem is that, since I have Windows 10, I can't use the Office 2010/2013 tutorials about making a self-certificate for VBA. Can I buy one? I am confused, and would like to resolve this quickly because I intend to install the front-end exe file onto several computers at work.

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: It will probably be easier to set the installation folder as "Trusted location": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509299/adding-trusted-location-to-access-run-time

Comment: As noted, you don't need any kind of certificates here. The only thing required is to set the folder location as a trusted location. In fact  you have to do this for the full edition of Access also - so the trusted location issue is not limited to using a accDE at all.