# How can I create a trusted ACCDE Access file?

Tags: ms-access

I would like to save an Access database as an ACCDE and also have it trusted. The reason being every time I open ACCDE I keep receiving the message:

"A potential security concern has been identified..."

I know that I can sign a ACCDC file with SelfCert.exe but thats not what I need.

**I want the Access File to end with ACCDE and have the message:
"A potential security concern has been identified..." not show up.**

Comment: There's no magic _automatically trust everything I write_ button. Either you create a self-signed certificate with SelfCert and manually add the certificate on all machines and trust it, or you buy a certificate and manuallly trust it, or you're out of luck.

Comment: See this for manual workaround. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469747/how-to-disable-access-security-notice-a-potential-security-concern-has-been-ide

Comment: I am aware of SelfCert but you cannot create a certificate for a ACCDE file

Answer (score 0):

You can create a registry key that will add the directory as a trusted location and will not show the warning anymore. What's nice about this method is that you can easily automate this to happen on the computers where you deploy your app. See method #2 or #3 in this blog: http://www.accessrepairnrecovery.com/blog/fix-microsoft-access-security-notice

And in case the blog ever gets removed, here is the important bits: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\Location20] “Path”=”C:\Database\” “Description”=”My Database location”

Explanation about the key: – The number “14.0” is the version of MS Office. You can change the numbers that represent the version you are executing.

– The “Location20” is a unique name that you assign. 20 can be any number that is not previously used. Other programs include default MS Access wizards, already have used other numbers. But if you want to make more than one path as trusted location, then each location must end up with different number.

– The “C:\Database\” is the physical path that you want to set to be as Trusted Location. You can place any path that you choose here.

By copy and pasting the above coding into a text file and save it with a name such as RemoveSecurityWarning.reg, you can then run the file into your PC’s registry just by making double click on the file.